# Reporting Services - User management & Security Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created an SSRS report with several tables using several stored procedures on SGMIS. The report is to be delivered either  by email in PDF format, or should be able to be run by the designated users on demand from the URL

The report runs fine, scheduled run is fine, sends the email with the report in PDF file attached.

Unfortunately whenever the user () tries to run it from the URL, she gets an error message like this:

```
The permissions granted to user 'mydomain\myAccount' 
are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) 
(ReportingServicesLibrary)
```

But the user definitely has all the permissions on the report server and the folder (so \CSC\ and the report itself) – we even checked that she has a login on the SQL Server, and she is mapped to the Public role on there and she has access to the database too.

What else do we need to do in order for a user who is not in the Systems dept. or admins to execute an SSRS report through the URL?

Comment: You again..?  Hey - dumb question, but did you check the last 2 paragraphs ("User Action") of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337279.aspx)?

Comment: I did but I guess I was looking for confirmation of what I should do? I am an Admin on the report and SQL Server, but surely the Browser user doesn't need to be an Admins?

Comment: Just curious if you've had any luck resolving this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my configuration, and I have the following:

- Login into the Reports Manager at `http://servername/reports`
- Select the folder the contains your reports, then click "Folder Settings". If the base folder contains the report, just click "Folder Settings" immediately.
- If not already selected, click "Security" on the left sidebar.
- Click "New Role Assignment".
- For Group or User Name, enter: `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users`
- Check off `Browser` in the list of roles.
- Click OK.

Comment: @OurManInBananas I'll take another look at my config and see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: @OurManInBananas Have you tried replacing `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` with the user that it's complaining about? (in your question, `mydomain\myAccount`)

Comment: yes, the users have been added as browsers, also they are on the SQL Server db as Public.

Comment: It turns out (after seeing [Lynn Crumbling](http://stackoverflow.com/users/656243/lynn-crumbling)'s answer) that as well as the report folder, and the report, we need to add the user to the Data Source folder